# invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python-3.x, django

Здравствуйте, 
При просмотре списка формируется ссылка для просмотра деталей объекта.
В просмотре id=''. В чем ошибка.

```
# models.py
class Object(models.Model):
    obj_code = models.FloatField(primary_key=True)
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('newsch:obj_detail', args=[str(self.obj_code)])

# temlpate
<a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ object.obj_code }} </td> 

#urls.py
 url(r'^obj_detail/(?P<id>)\d+/$', views.obj_detail, name='obj_detail')

# views.py
def obj_detail(request, id):
    object = get_object_or_404( Object, obj_code=int(id) )
    return render(request, 'newsch/object/obj_detail.html',  {'object': object})
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема здесь:

```
obj_code=int(id)
```

Вы пытаетесь перевести в строку то, что нельзя перевести в строку(пробел, какой-то 
 другой символ, и т.д. )
 вариант 1

```
obj_code=int(''.join(x for x in id if x.isdigit()))
```

вариант 2

```
import re
obj_code = int(re.search(r'\d+', id).group())
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Эти варианты не работают.

Comment: На странице отображается число-ссылка 943631 (url = 'http://.../obj_detail/9436310/' В просмотр 'obj_detail' должно было бы передать значение 943631 в переменную 'id'. Но туда вообще ничего не передается. Если заменить код на 'object = get_object_or_404( Object, obj_code=943631 )' тогда работает.